# Read each line of a file using fscanf

Tags: c, scanf, dat-protocol

I am trying to read each line of a .dat file and store it in a float number. I'm using fscanf. My goal is store these lines to after I raffle.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char url[]="PREMIOS.dat", nome[20];
    float premio[12];
    FILE *arq;

    arq = fopen(url, "r");
    if (arq == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
    } else {
        for(i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            while((fscanf(arq, "%f\n", &premio[i])) != EOF)
                printf("%.2f\n", premio[i]);
        }
    }
    fclose(arq);
    return 0;
}
```

The .dat file:

```
100.00
900.00
600.00
1000.00
0.00
400.00
200.00
800.00
0.01
300.00
500.00
700.00
```

This code can't storage the numbers for some reason. How can i read these numbers as float, storage and after that raffle?

Comment: Please tidy up your code

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  1) ...:13:13: error: ‘i’ undeclared (first use in this function)  2) a warning about a variable being set but not used.  3) a warning about a unused variable.   Please correct your code and post an edit to your question

Comment: regarding: `while((fscanf(arq, "%f\n", &premio[i])) != EOF)
                printf("%.2f\n", premio[i]);`   This `while()` will read everything from `arq`  and place ALL the read entries into `premio[0]`.  Then fail the `while()` immediately for all values of `i` in range 1...11

Comment: regarding: `printf("Error\n");`  1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error indication is from a C library function should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest using; `perror( "fopen for URL.data for input failed" );`   Followed by `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   The call to `exit()` is because after the 'if/else' code blocks, when the call to `fopen()` has failed, there is no open file pointer to pass to `fclose()`, so a runtime error will occur.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char ... nome[20];` That char array is never referenced again in the posted code, so why is it even declared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (fscanf(arq, "%f\n", &premio[i])) != EOF )
       printf("%.2f\n", premio[i]);
```

Will continue reading the file line-by-line, till the end of file. In that case, only the value at index 0 of `premio` is being overwritten each time.

Instead you should try something along the lines of,

```
If ((fscanf(arq, "%f\n", &premio[i])) != EOF )
       printf("%.2f\n", premio[i]);
```